# How to make a facebook app send notification to user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

is there a way I can make my app send a notification or private message to a user inviting him to use the app?

Lets say I want to invite my friends to use an app but I dont want them to know that I invited them, so the app would notify something like: "One of your friends invited you to use this app!"

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I direct-message a Facebook user from my app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4257566/how-can-i-direct-message-a-facebook-user-from-my-app)

Comment: No. Facebook needs it to be not anonymous and user triggered/initiated to stop App Developers spamming users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only a registered user can get the notification from the App, using [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/).

Comment: You add that this API is quite new and doesn't exists when the OP ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can send notifications via facebook apps to any user on facebook but you must be his/her faceook friend.